# Why is sssd an unrecognized service, even though it is installed and can be restarted?

Tags: 14.04, services, pam, sssd

Why is sssd an unrecognized service, even though it is installed and can be restarted?
BTW: This concerns Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, it was not like that in 12.04
I will show what I mean below, I think it is a bug but I am interested in an explanation and/or workaround.

```
root@tauriel:~/scripts# service sssd
**sssd: unrecognized service**
root@tauriel:~/scripts# service sssd status
sssd start/running, process 22454
root@tauriel:~/scripts# service sssd restart
sssd stop/waiting
sssd start/running, process 22485
root@tauriel:~/scripts# service sssd status
sssd start/running, process 22485
root@tauriel:~/scripts# service sssd
**sssd: unrecognized service**
root@tauriel:~/scripts#
```

BTW: sssd is apparently a new tag, it would be nice if it was added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you run `service`, if there's a sysv init script, it will call that script (or call Upstart, if it's an Upstart job):

```
$ service ssh
 * Usage: /etc/init.d/ssh {start|stop|reload|force-reload|restart|try-restart|status}
$ service gdm
/etc/init.d/gdm: 79: /etc/init.d/gdm: Syntax error: "fi" unexpected (expecting "}")
```

Naturally if you don't pass a command (`restart`, `status`, etc.), only these scripts will be able to respond. If the init file for a service is Upstart-only, this will fail:

```
$ service tty1
tty1: unrecognized service
```

SSSD only offers an Upstart init script, as you can see from the list of files in [`sssd-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/sssd-common/filelist).

---

This behaviour is not exactly well documented in the [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/service). However, if you examine the `service` command, which is a shell script:

```bsh
118 if [ -r "/etc/init/${SERVICE}.conf" ] && which initctl >/dev/null \
119    && initctl version | grep -q upstart
120 then
121    # Upstart configuration exists for this job and we're running on upstart
122    case "${ACTION}" in
```

The actions in this `case` consists of `exec` calls of `initctl` (via its symlinked versions - `start`, `stop`, etc.). Since the `ACTION` variable is empty and doesn't match any case, it falls through to:

```bsh
138 
139 # Otherwise, use the traditional sysvinit
140 if [ -x "${SERVICEDIR}/${SERVICE}" ]; then
141    exec env -i LANG="$LANG" PATH="$PATH" TERM="$TERM" "$SERVICEDIR/$SERVICE" ${ACTION} ${OPTIONS}
142 else
143    echo "${SERVICE}: unrecognized service" >&2
144    exit 1
145 fi
```

Here you can see why it produces that error.

Comment: Thank you for the answer muru.
I also noticed that it is not listed when doing a "service --status-all"
What is the best current method to see the status of all/any deamons, when they are started and how can you control it? 
(update-rc.d doesn't work since the  /etc/init.d/sssd does not exist)

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to use a combination of methods. For the status of all services, do `service --status-all; initctl list`. `initctl` is used to handle Upstart services, and `list` will show the current status as well. To control the starting of an Upstart service try using [override files](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#override-files).

Comment: I just noticed that after an apt-update && apt-upgrade (Ubuntu 14.04)
sssd didn't want to start automatically anymore.
Following your instructions, I looked inside /etc/init/sssd.conf and found a difference with another host:
"start on (filesystem and net-device-up and starting autofs)"
=================
I changed it into
=================
"start on (filesystem and net-device-up)"
=================
And now sssd starts up on boot again.
I know it is kluge, but an interesting workaround I think.